# How to sort categorical values by an arbitrary order?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have a table called `ANIMALS` which looks like this

```
| name      | category |
------------------------
| fluffer   | CAT      |
| tooter    | ELEPHANT |
| tooter_jr | ELEPHANT |
| woofer    | DOG      |
```

If I sort the table by category then I will get all `CAT`s then `DOG`s then `ELEPHANT`s. But I need to order the table such that the sequence is `CAT` > `ELEPHANT` > `DOG`

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Create a table (category - sorting weight) and use it in the query. Or use any trick (expression like `ORDER BY INSTR('CAT,ELEPHANT,DOG', category,1,1)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
WITH
Animals (name, category) AS (
 SELECT 'fluffer', 'CAT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'tooter', 'ELEPHANT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'tooter_jr', 'ELEPHANT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'woofer', 'DOG' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
  name, category
FROM Animals
ORDER BY
  CASE category
  WHEN 'CAT' THEN 1
  WHEN 'ELEPHANT' THEN 2
  WHEN 'DOG' THEN 3
  END
;
```

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: I am getting `error: Error: ORA-00904: "DOG": invalid identifier`

I am still doing a little trial and error.

Comment: Oh ok. I was doing

```
ORDER BY
  CASE category
  WHEN ${TYPES.CAT} THEN 1
  WHEN ${TYPES.ELEPHANT} THEN 2
  WHEN ${TYPES.DOG} THEN 3
  END
;
``` 

instead of 

```
ORDER BY
  CASE category
  WHEN '${TYPES.CAT}' THEN 1
  WHEN '${TYPES.ELEPHANT}' THEN 2
  WHEN '${TYPES.DOG}' THEN 3
  END
;
```